# Product images uploaded are in the cached folder with a different size. Why?

Tags: image, cache, ce-1.9.1.0, media

Just found this issue, and look forward to getting advice from you:

For the product image uploaded via admin page, when it shows in the product page, or at home page, the source codes shows that it is loaded from a path like this:

http://[magentosite]/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/600x480/445dssfjdsjflsdrtowrs4343a67i/1/6/image.png

The actual product image has only dimension of 400x400, the cached image from the above path has dimension of 600x480.

The resized image (to 600x480) has a much bigger size, which causes slow site speed.

The list.phtml and media.phtml only resize the image to 135, 56, and 265.

Can anyone share your idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Did you set up a custom design or install a theme? Guess the image is somewhere included like this: `<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(600, 480); ?>`

Comment: Yes, you are right! The two files exist in the custom theme folder. Need to modify them to rectify the issues.

Comment: You're welcome! I've added my comment as answer. Please accept it to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files are created by calling the following from a template file:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(600, 480); ?>
```

As this image-size is not Magento default, there might be a custom design or installed theme that causes this generation.

As stated in the comments, the reason was that the two files existed in the custom theme folder and the solution is to update them.